# Is there any way in the android studio to pass a colllection reference from one activity to another activity in accessing the firebase firestore?

Tags: android

I need to Send my collection reference from one activity to another In android studio.Is there anyway that i can send my collection reference object from one activity to another as i am accessing the firebase firestore

Comment: Pass the path to the collection, not the collection itself

Comment: can i send my collection reference to the another activity???

Comment: You can maintain a static reference to the reference(DatabaseReference or StorageReference) and access it in all activities

Comment: Why you want that in the first place? Can't you just access firebase on the other activity?

Comment: to access the static reference the accessing class needs to be static??

Comment: i need the same reference in all the other activity

Answer (score -1):

Create a modal class of collection and implement `Serializable`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("referenceValue", collectionObject) // this way you can pass collection reference by implementing Serializable
startActivity()
```

In NextActivity.class

```
yourExpectedrefrence = (collectionClassName) 
getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("referenceValue");
```